# insert edgeloop tool via MEL scripting for maya

Tags: maya, mel

Does anyone know how to write a mel script that can ideally use a feature from the tool box ( EG. insert edgeloop tool?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you make an operation in maya, you'll get a MEL command echo in the script editor.

In this case, for 'insert edgeloop' operation I got something like: `polySplitRing -ch on -splitType 1 -weight 0.420764 -smoothingAngle 30 -fixQuads 1 -insertWithEdgeFlow 0 ;`

You can then look further into maya's MEL command documentation: https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/
and search for `polySplitRing` command: it lists all the arguments for this command and some examples.